# Php xpath create an array from data attributes

Tags: php, xpath

Is it possible to create an array from the following xml structure:

```
<language>
  <data section="Section 1">String 1</data>
  <data section="Section 1">String 2</data>
  <data section="Section 1">String 3</data>

  <data section="Section 2">String 4</data>
  <data section="Section 2">String 5</data>
  <data section="Section 2">String 6</data>

  <data section="Section 3">String 7</data>
  <data section="Section 3">String 8</data>
  <data section="Section 3">String 9</data>
</language>

$xmlel = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
```

What I would like to do is using:

```
$xmlel->xpath()
```

extract data attribute called "section" and converted into array, The expected result should have a unique values like:

```
[section] => Array
    (
        [0] => Section 1
        [1] => Section 2
        [2] => Section 3
    )
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath expression you're looking for to get unique results is:

```
//data[not(@section = preceding-sibling::data/@section)]/@section
```

This grabs section attributes from data elements where there are no prior sibling data elements with section attributes of the same value.

---

#### DOM Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("file.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//data[not(@section = preceding-sibling::data/@section)]/@section';
foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $text) {
    $sections[] = $text->value;
}

print_r($sections);
```

#### SimpleXML Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

$query = '//data[not(@section = preceding-sibling::data/@section)]/@section';
foreach ($xml->xpath($query) as $text) {
    $sections[] = (string)$text;
}

print_r($sections);
```

---

#### Output for either:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Section 1
    [1] => Section 2
    [2] => Section 3
)
```